# MySQL retrieve values before specific strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have multiple rows in my database with a description in one of the following formats:

```
SC068 NGN 399ppc + 139ppm
SC068 NGN 139ppm
SC079 NGN 200ppc + 200ppm (After 60 Seconds)
SC060 NGN 200ppc
```

How can I retrieve the numbers before `ppc` and/or `ppm` ?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are these strings? A database table consists of columns, so why not store the values separately in the first place? Apart from that you can easily look up MySQL's string functions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html.

Comment: since you haven't done any research perhaps you're lost at where to start a small nudge for dealing with the question you asked specifically you can loop over your column using a WHILE loop and inside of it you can use [string_split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) to split up everything where there is a white space. At which point you can search that table with a like `%pcc%` or like `%ppm%` and extract the ###ppc, ###ppm via multiple methods one can be replacing pcc or ppm with an empty string no spaces via REPLACE

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - great idea in theory.  In practice not always viable, especially if you're working with an existing data structure (some CRM/ERP type software have notoriously bad data structures behind the scenes for example...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each appears only once, you can do:

```
select (case when col like '%ppm%'
             then substring_index(substring_index(col, 'ppm', 1), ' ', -1) + 0 
        end) as ppm_num,
       (case when col like '%ppc%'
             then substring_index(substring_index(col, 'ppc', 1), ' ', -1) + 0
        end) as ppc_num
```

These work for only the first appearance in the string.  The `+ 0` does silent conversion of the characters before the keywords to a number.

Comment: thank you for this - this has really helped. the only issue i can see when running the query is a value like this `SC060 NGN 200ppc` returns 200 for both columns

Comment: you can use CASE WHEN

Answer (score 0):

based on Gordon's, you can use CASE WHEN

```
SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(description,'ppm') <> 0
            THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, 'ppm', 1), ' ', -1) + 0
            WHEN INSTR(description,'ppc') <> 0
            THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, 'ppc', 1), ' ', -1) + 0
            ELSE ''
        END instr_num
  FROM t
```

Sample data

```
CREATE TABLE t
(description VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO t VALUES('SC068 NGN 399ppc + 139ppm');
INSERT INTO t VALUES('SC068 NGN 139ppm');
INSERT INTO t VALUES('SC079 NGN 200ppc + 200ppm (After 60 Seconds)');
INSERT INTO t VALUES('SC060 NGN 200ppc');
```

Result

```
instr_num
139
139
200
200
```

Comment: but this will only get the first instance of the number whether it is ppc or ppm